# making memory window in windbg to show one column

Tags: windbg

at the moment, when I use the memory window in windbg, it shows two columns:
[memory display - current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfZUD.png)

is there a way to configure it to only show one column?

my memory tab configuration is as below:

[memory config - size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq8qI.png)

[memory config - format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYGDT.png)

[memory config - text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvdvv.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to have two columns in the memory window. If you need to dump data in a single column for a specific reason, you could consider using the console command "dq", which takes a parameter "/c " to control columns. For instance:

```
0:000> dq /c1
00007ffb`d78c0930  8d7ffe03`3025148b
00007ffb`d78c0938  2b3fe083`c28b404f
00007ffb`d78c0940  334cc8d3`49c28bc8
```